# How to Rake task generate in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in ROR and im using  version Ruby 1.9.3 & Rails 3.1.0.

I want to generate rake task. How to generate rake take?

i am using below code for generate  rake task in commend prompt.

```
rails generate task permission my_task1 my_task2
```

But every time give message **"Could not find generator task"**

Please help.

Comment: For future visitors: I was able to run the exact command given here successfully without any error on Ruby 2.7.3 and Rails 6.1.4.1.

Answer (score 15):

You create a new file in `lib/tasks` like `lib/tasks/your_task.rake`.

You add a new task to that file:

```
namespace :my_app do
  desc "a new task to be executed"
  task :my_task do
    puts "hello rake"
  end
end
```

This would be called like `rake my_app:my_task`

---

## Update

The task generator was added in Rails 3.2.0

Answer (score 3):

Haven't found the reason for this question why rails generating error. So i have done bit searching somewhere else and found this. May this help.
Use this instead -

```
      bundle exec rails g task permission my_task1 my_task2
```

Rails is not able to find task so this is a work around to get you going.

[Source](https://blog.widefix.com/how-to-generate-rake-task/)

Comment: using bundler won't add that generator to rails

Comment: By the way this helped me. So i shared this.

Answer (score 0):

**syntax:** `rails g task permission my_task1 my_task2`

```
namespace :permission do
  desc "relevant to your task functionality"
  task :my_task1 => :environment do
  end

  desc "relevant to your task functionality"
  task :my_task2 => :environment do
  end
end
```

Comment: the problem seems to be that invoking this results in an error.